# How to check WHERE > 0

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT IFNULL(sum(a.id),0) as id, 
       p.username 
FROM pool_worker p 
LEFT JOIN 
(
  (SELECT count(id) as id, username 
   FROM shares 
   WHERE time > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) 
   GROUP BY username
  ) 
  UNION 
  (SELECT count(id) as id, username 
   FROM shares_history 
   WHERE time > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) 
   GROUP BY username
  )
) a ON p.username=a.username GROUP BY username
```

This is my query I am using for my 3 tables basically it is layouted like this

```
pool_worker
->username
->speed

shares
->username

shares_history
->username
```

I only want to grab the data from shares and shares_history if pool_worker.speed > 0

can someone help me here?

Comment: So why not add `WHERE p.speed > 0` before the final `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
SELECT IFNULL(sum(a.id),0) as id, 
   p.username 
FROM pool_worker p 
LEFT JOIN 
(
  (SELECT count(id) as id, username 
   FROM shares 
   WHERE time > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) 
   GROUP BY username
  ) 
  UNION 
  (SELECT count(id) as id, username 
   FROM shares_history 
   WHERE time > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) 
   GROUP BY username
  )
) a ON p.username=a.username
WHERE p.speed > 0
GROUP BY p.username
```

Comment: I just realized that. I was ttrying to do From pool_worker p where p.speed >0  and it wasn't working. thanks.

Comment: to my knowledge the aboue one should work, try my query pls:

`SELECT IFNULL(sum(a.id),0) as id, p.username FROM (select * from pool_worker where speed>0) p LEFT JOIN ( (SELECT count(id) as id, username FROM shares WHERE time > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) GROUP BY username ) UNION (SELECT count(id) as id, username FROM shares_history WHERE time > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) GROUP BY username ) ) a ON p.username=a.username GROUP BY p.username`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT IFNULL(sum(a.id),0) as id, 
       p.username 
FROM pool_worker p 
LEFT JOIN 
(
  (SELECT count(id) as id, username 
   FROM shares 
   WHERE time > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) 
   GROUP BY username
  ) 
  UNION 
  (SELECT count(id) as id, username 
   FROM shares_history 
   WHERE time > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) 
   GROUP BY username
  )
) a ON p.username=a.username 
WHERE p.speed > 0
GROUP BY username
```

Answer (score 0):

or like that?

```
SELECT IFNULL(sum(a.id),0) as id, 
       p.username 
FROM pool_worker p 
LEFT JOIN 
(
  (SELECT count(id) as id, username 
   FROM shares 
   WHERE time > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) 
   GROUP BY username
  ) 
  UNION 
  (SELECT count(id) as id, username 
   FROM shares_history 
   WHERE time > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) 
   GROUP BY username
  )
) a ON p.username=a.username AND NOT p.speed IS NULL AND p.speed>0
GROUP BY username
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT IFNULL(sum(a.id),0) as id, p.username FROM 
(select * from pool_worker where speed>0) p 
LEFT JOIN 
  ( 
    (SELECT count(id) as id, username FROM shares WHERE time > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) GROUP BY username ) 
UNION 
    (SELECT count(id) as id, username FROM shares_history WHERE time > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) GROUP BY username )
 ) a 
ON p.username=a.username GROUP BY p.username`